# Making noise on a wire

Tags: noise

For some educational purpose I want to make some noises on breadboard wires but they barely become noisy , I'd transfer my data with 5v electrical potential on 50cm wire length, I tried multiple strategies like adding resistors or passing high amperage wire near breadboard wires but still no noise,is there any other way to generate noise on a wire?

Comment: Noise comes in lots of different types.  Do you have a preference? Transient? Continuous? Low frequency? High frequency?

Comment: You could try a high gain transistor (Darlington perhaps) with a short floating wire attached to the base pin.  It would pick up environmental noise and superimpose an amplified version of it on the emitter.  Such a trick is used in cheap "ghost detector" toy kits for kids.

Comment: My signal is continuous and clock pulse frequency is 1MHz

Comment: If you have any crappy old line-powered electric drills, they can make dandy noise sources.  New ones in good shape aren't as good, but may work.  Hold the trigger, wave it around the vicinity of your electronics.  (I learned this from a tech in aerospace, who kept one for just that purpose in the bottom drawer of his tool box).

Answer (score 2):

To simulate the crosstalk of 2 adjacent tracks, use AWG30 twisted pair with 1MHz signals and low f CMOS on others.

Terminating your 1MHz with capacitance increases HF current and reduces voltage rise time while using a 50~100 Ohm load reduces current but maintains dV/dt rise time

Crosstalk Noise may occur by 1/x gap that controls capacitance coupling of dV/dt or high current dI/dt via line inductance, (ESL).

If you want to inject noise on 1MHz then use a relay coil current in a loop so it faces close to 1MHz current loop  If you want voltage noise then bring parallel wires closer together (eg twisted pair.) Then drive a relay coil (with diode) with say a 10 Hz sig gen + transistor.  This could damage CMOS from overvoltage after logic errors by 1/x [mm] separation. Other common noise sources are a brushed drill motor current wire loop near the signal's wire loop.

If you want to see 1MHz clock noise with 10ns rise time causing crosstalk then use twisted pair with another noise signal to measure the dV/dt crosstalk.  But scope probe ground must be very short for signals <= 10ns rise time.

For ESD test purposes [read this](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/6d/41/b5/24/c1/4d/47/f5/CD00004125.pdf/files/CD00004125.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00004125.pdf)

## anecdote

In my 1st job, I had a 1 day task to fix someone else's design of a system with a 20 PCB card cage with a wirewrap backplane. It was all AWG30 solid wirewrap in neat busses of Aircraft style wire bundles with TTL slew rates.  The look of *grief* when I told her it had to be redone, random point-to-point made me think this was worse than what she faced crossing the Berlin wall to come to Canada.  Noise crosstalk was unbearable but surmountable to save the life of the project.

Comment: But it was NEAT. Good products are clean and NEAT, right?

Comment: When it comes to backplanes with WW, spider web mess gives cleaner signals, and twisted pair is even cleaner. in the next building where they overhauled CAF jets with new Radar and paint, the QA guys inspected and posted a bag of loose things found on inspection of the aircraft. Peer pressure.